# hosted BigQuery instance

Tags: hadoop, google-bigquery, bigdata

Is there any way I can host big query software on my company server?
The company does not want the data to be anywhere else other than own data center.

What are BigQuery alternatives? (cloud as well as hosted)

Comment: See bottom page: http://www.pentahobigdata.com/ecosystem/platforms/hadoop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any way I can host big query software on my company server?

[Google Big Query](https://cloud.google.com/products/big-query) is an implementation of the [Google Dremel Paper](http://research.google.com/pubs/pub36632.html), but is offered as a service and is not available as a software to be installed in-premise.

> What are big query alternatives? (cloud as well as hosted)

[Apache Drill](http://incubator.apache.org/drill/) is an implementation of the above mentioned Dremel, but has just started and might take some time to materialize.

Cloudera has recently announced Imapala for real-time queries on Hadoop. Check the [blog](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/10/cloudera-impala-real-time-queries-in-apache-hadoop-for-real/) for more details.

*Would be interested to know some other alternatives for real-time queries on Big Data.*

Edit : Here is an interesting article from [InfoWorld](http://www.infoworld.com/print/205879) on the same.

Answer (score 1):

Hive and Pig are two common solutions to making a queryable system, but since you mentioned Google's Big Query, I assume you mean real-time queries.

In addition to the real-time solutions mentioned by Praveen, there are some workarounds to making other column-oriented solutions faster by writing redundant stores, in a normalized fashion.  Think of it this way:  You can 'pre-join' the data in a column family, as long as you understand that you're trading fast access against excess volume and slower insertion speed.

-t.